# Compiling openssl for armv7

Tags: c, makefile, openssl, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile openssl for armv7. I have cross compiled a few other libraries on this build machine. With openssl I am getting an error that I am not able to understand.

Here is what I have done

1) Ran configure as follows

```
./Configure --prefix=/home/sridhar/openssl-arm -march=armv7-a -L/armhome/sysroot/usr/lib -L/armhome/sysroot/lib --cross-compile-prefix=/armhome/gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- linux-armv4
```

/armhome has cross compiling tools and sysroot for arm

2) `make`

It runs for a while and at the end fails with the following output. It is not able to find **/lib/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a**  files, but I have specified different library locations using -L option.  I am confused as to why it /lib and /usr/lib are in search path

```
 make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sridhar/openssl/openssl'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/armhome/sysroot/usr/lib:/armhome/sysroot/lib: /armhome/gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="/home/sridhar/openssl-arm/ssl" -DENGINESDIR="/home/sridhar/openssl-arm/lib/engines-1.1" -Wall -O3 -pthread -march=armv7-a -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -Wl,-znodelete -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-soname=libcrypto.so.1.1 -o ./libcrypto.so.1.1 -Wl,--whole-archive,--version-script=crypto.map ./libcrypto.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl -L/armhome/sysroot/usr/lib -L/armhome/sysroot/lib

/armhome/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0
/armhome/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5.3.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.shared:197: recipe for target 'link_shlib.linux-shared' failed
make[2]: *** [link_shlib.linux-shared] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sridhar/openssl/openssl'
Makefile:732: recipe for target 'libcrypto.so' failed
make[1]: *** [libcrypto.so] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sridhar/openssl/openssl'
Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You did not configure the OpenSSL library correctly. See [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. Also see the various OpenSSL README's that describe the process for different platforms.

Comment: If `/armhome/sysroot/usr/` is your sysroot, then you should add it as a `CFLAGS` options: `CFLAGS="-isysroot=/armhome/sysroot/usr/ ..."`. Adding the sysroot to everything you are building means the system's headers and library files will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Maybe a bit late for op but as @jww mentioned you need to export not just `CFLAGS` but `LDFLAGS` also with `--sysroot=/path/to/sysroot/`